# "With respect to" in mathematics

Tags: idiom, preposition, science, mathematics

The expression "with respect to" is common in mathematics.
Consider these example sentences:

1. The derivative of `x^2y` with respect to `y` is `x^2`.
2. Let us reflect the point `A` with respect to the line `L` and call the new point `B`.

(This SE site doesn't support MathJax, so I'm not formatting the formulas at all. Using dollars would probably confuse users here.)

I would like to be able to translate these sentences like these in Latin.
I believe such things can be found in scientific texts written in Latin, but I am not familiar with this literature.
**Is there an attested Latin idiom for the mathematical "with respect to"?**

By best guess is *respectu* with genitive.
Using my examples:

1. Derivativus expressionis `x^2y` respectu (variabilis) `y` est `x^2`.
2. Punctum `A` reflectimus respectu lineae `L` et punctum novum `B` appellamus.

I later asked a separate [question about reading mathematics out loud in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1937/79).

My feeling is that using a mere preposition or case is not enough.
(Although in a sense the whole "with respect to" is a preposition.)
As a mathematician myself, I find it beneficial to have a somewhat heavier structure to make it more easily recognizable.

Comment: How close to 'in respect to' is the legal expression **in rem** +genitive?

Comment: @Hugh, I'm not familiar with that legal expression, so I can't tell. Quick searches suggest that not very close.

Comment: *quoad* is my first-draw reaction, but I can't back that up with actual Latin mathematical texts.

Comment: @brianpck, how would you use that in a sentence? For example, what would be "reflection with respect to a line"?

Comment: A quick Google search seems to suggest I'm right: [*Principia calculi differentialis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-pBmvAWJpGAC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22quoad+x%22) or just search for "quoad x." I'll try to turn that into an answer when I have time.

Comment: @brianpck, that would be great. Take your time. (Indeed, *quoad x* seems mean what I want.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is one word that seems to fit the bill: [*quoad*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquoad). Although this word has a temporal ("as long as") and spatial ("as far as") meaning, Lewis and Short also gives the following meaning:

> B.3: With respect to, as to

It also suggests that it derives from *quod attinet ad*. An interesting note is that all three classical examples given are *dubious readings*, so we cannot say that there is a rock-solid classical testimony that this word can be used like a normal PREP + ACC.

That said, here are several usages in later mathematical works that use *quoad* in the same context as the OP's example sentences. (I don't know how to do do mathematical notation: feel free to edit.)

[*Principia calculi differentialis et integralis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-pBmvAWJpGAC&pg=PA28), Andrea Caraffa

> denotabunt itaque f<sub>x</sub>'(x,y,z,...), f<sub>x</sub>"(x,y,z,...), ... derivatas primi, secundi, ... ordinis ex f(x,y,z,...) **quoad x**, item f<sub>y</sub>'(x,y,z,...), f<sub>y</sub>"(x,y,z,...), ... derivatas primi, secundi, ... ordinis ex f(x,y,z,...) **quoad y**; etc. (pg. 28)

Another quote from the same page uses the same word, but also uses *respectu ipsius* to mean something else. (My multi-variable differential calculus is rusty, so perhaps a comment could clarify what the distinction should be):

> Ex functione  μ = f(x, y, z...) exsistunt etiam partiales variorum ordinum derivatae *per vices* quoad binas, ternas, ... variabiles v. gr. quoad y, x, quoad z, y, x, etc.; sic ax<sup>a-1</sup>cos(y) est partialis derivata secundi ordinis ex functione x<sup>a</sup>sin(y) quoad y, x, nimirum derivata **quoad x** ex derivata **quoad y respectu ipsius x<sup>a</sup>sin(y)**. (pg. 28)

Another,example of this usage comes from the [*Tentamen*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EENYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=%22quoad+x%22&source=bl&ots=P1Lk0_bIUu&sig=CMO2q7VwrvY8ip78oriEHkmo9dc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2gYaH9__OAhXPth4KHeZXC8IQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22quoad%20x%22&f=false) of Wolfgangus Bolyai de Bolya (pg. 221), talking about differentials. This is significant because he is explicitly instructing on proper terminology:

> tum vz(dot) dicitur *differentiale quoad z* et uẋ quoad x acceptum, atque v dicitur *derivata ipsius U quoad z* et u derivata quoad x accepta...

Searching for [*"quoad x"*](https://www.google.com/search?#q=%22quoad+x%22) with quotes reveals numerous other examples.

Comment: Good answer! I assume the mathematical "with respect to" in the modern sense as an idea did not exist in antiquity, so attested classical examples are too much to ask for. If I had a declinable word instead of a variable name, would *quoad* take a nominative or an accusative?

Comment: The examples given in L&S use the accusative. I also remembered why I remembered the word so quickly: it's very common in Scholastic Latin. Just try searching for *quoad* in the [*Corpus Thomisticum*](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age)

Comment: What about [_erga_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=erga#lexicon)?